# Gostaria de atribuir o dia de ontem como Data inicial toda vez que o meu programa fosse iniciado num dateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2017

1. Consigo atribuir valor para ele só não sei como atribuir um yesterday

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```